# Difference between "abolish" and "rescind"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-difference, connotations

I have attempted an English test, where a question was given as

> **Following the students’ ______, the authorities have finally_______ the rule of having CCTV’s in the classroom.**

And the options were given as

> Protests, abolished
>
> Agitations, rescind
>
> Agitations, abolish
>
> Agitations, rescinded

I thought both the first and fourth options can be right here but the test claims fourth option as an answer but first option as wrong answer.

Aren't they mean same? Or is there any difference between those two verbs?

I've looked up dictionary and these two words are given as synonyms to each other. So, either of the two options can fit here.

But the explanation is given as "we choose *rescinded* because it means to *cancel a law or rule* and thus fits the context. *Abolish* means to formally put an end to a system or institution or practice. So, it doesn't fit here"

Please explain to me if there is any difference and tell me whether the explanation given by the test is right or not.

Comment: Is **agitations** the right word? Can we eliminate that pair because of it?

Comment: @TRomano So, do you mean **Agitations** is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a difficult question involving the meaning of these terms throughout the English-speaking world. The distinction between **agitations** and **protests** is clearer, IMO, than that between **abolished** and **rescinded**, when viewed across all dialects of English. If you check ngram for frequency, "abolished the rule" occurs rather more frequently than "rescinded the rule", so **abolish** is clearly not incorrect even if rescinded is a viable option. On the other hand, **agitations** in much of the English-speaking world has connotations of disorder and unrest, even if, in India (per the *Oxford Living Dictionary*, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/agitation) it may lack such connotations and may mean simply a public demonstration.

P.S. To my ear, if the examiners are going to have you choose between protests/abolished and agitations/rescinded, they should also be aware of the clunkiness of "the rule *of having*" which would be better as "the rule *requiring*...".

Comment: But google ngram viewer also didn't show any results for _abolished the rule_. Could you please share the link?

Comment: @Ganesh.R - "Abolish" isn't completely *wrong*, but "rescind" is "more right".  *Abolish* means something more like "permanently end an institution or practice", like "The nation abolished slavery in 1877" or "After the resignation of King Harald, the monarchy was abolished."  *Rescind* means more specifically "to repeal a law, a regulation, or an order", so it's a closer fit for what's meant.

Comment: @Ganesh.R - Also, I don't know how you were searching Ngrams, but yes, it does show results for *abolished the rule*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abolished+the+rule%2Crescinded+the+rule&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabolished%20the%20rule%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crescinded%20the%20rule%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @stangdon Sorry. Something wrong with my [search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Abolished+the+rule%2Crescinded+the+rule&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crescinded%20the%20rule%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @stangdon In fact, I've chosen the first option. But I got negative marks for this question. I want to make a representation against the given answer so that I'll get more marks. Can I report to the examiners about this?

Comment: @Ganesh.R - You can always try, but I wouldn't expect them to reconsider their decision, given that *rescind* looks like a better choice than *abolish*.  (But then again, I think *protests* works better than *agitations*, so I don't think any of the choices is very good.)

Answer (score 0):

*Rescind X* means "to make a previously issued law, decree, or order X void." - it's equivalent to *cancel X*.

*Abolish X* means "to get rid of X entirely" - X usually being a phenomenon or something that is not physical and not a law, decree, or order. Examples: "I'm going to abolish poverty, slavery, hunger, his resistance."

You don't usually *abolish* a law but you might abolish something the law allowed with a new law.

Comment: So, do you mean first option is completely wrong here?

Comment: Rules aren't laws and they are not physical, so yeah, they can be abolished.

Answer (score -1):

The option 4 is right fitted here.

Abolish: Put an end to
Rescind: Put an end to (a law or agreement) officially.

Hence, rescind has the most close meaning for your English test question.